# How to make Bluetooth 5.0 dongle work in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, usb, 22.04, bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and I tried to connect a Bluetooth 5.0 dongle. The Bluetooth appears in Settings, but I can't connect to any Bluetooth devices. I have a dual boot on my desktop, so I tried it on Windows 10 and the USB Bluetooth 5.0 worked flawlessly.

I am just wondering, is it possible to get the USB Bluetooth 5.0 to work with Linux? I've seen some threads on the Internet and downloaded the `mp_rtl8761b_fw`, `rtl8761bu_fw`, `rtl8761b_config` drivers, but nothing yet.

Thank you for your help!